# Dx11 Crash when accessing XMMATRIX

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I've been creating a flocking swarm project in DirectX 11 and had an error where I try and create a vector of Pointers to objects and on the 3rd iteration of pushing back it will crash and jump to this:

```
XMFINLINE _XMMATRIX& _XMMATRIX::operator=
(
    CONST _XMMATRIX& M
)
{
    r[0] = M.r[0];
    r[1] = M.r[1];
    r[2] = M.r[2];
    r[3] = M.r[3];
    return *this;
}
```

the crash happens when I execute this code:

```
Populate();

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_numOfPrey; i++)
{
    m_preyVec[i]->LoadContent(dx, colour, yaw, pitch, roll, scale);

    srand (time(NULL));
    XMFLOAT3 tempPos;

    tempPos.x = rand() % 40;
    tempPos.y = rand() % 40;
    tempPos.z = rand() % 40;

    m_preyVec[i]->SetPosition(tempPos);
}

return true;
```

Populate function:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_numOfPrey; i++)
{
    Prey* newPrey = new Prey();
    m_preyVec.push_back(newPrey);
}
```

EDIT: the prey inherits from a vehicle class (which builds the buffers, FX and InputLayout for the vehicle used my the Prey and Predator.

so this is the Prey LoadContent();

```
{
    Vehicle::LoadContent(dx, colour, yaw, pitch, roll, scale);
    return true;
}
```

and this is the Vehicle LoadContent();

```
{
    if(!GameObject::LoadContent(dx, m_position, colour, yaw, pitch, roll, scale))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(!BuildBuffers(dx))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(!BuildFX(dx))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(!BuildInputLayout(dx))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, if I need to provide more info I can do that as well, as I've been stuck on this for days and I'm sure it's something small I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Show us the constructor of `Prey`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure that the `XMVECTOR` & `XMMATRIX` types from DXMath are correctly aligned to 16-bytes ([see the docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Properly_Align_Alloc)), for stack allocations, this is automatic, but for heap allocations, you need to use `_aligned_malloc` to get correctly aligned memory. Alternatively you can use the `XMFLOATn` and `XMFLOATnxn` for store and use the unaligned vector loads when you actually work with them.

For classes or structs that contain XM types you can overcome this by overloading the `new` operator to do explicitly align allocations; the easiest is by deriving from a template such as this (note: this isn't complete, the are a few types of [operator `new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) & `delete`):

```
template <size_t align> class AlignedAllocPolicy
{
public:
    void* operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        return _aligned_malloc(size,align);
    }

    void operator delete(void* mem)
    {
        _aligned_free(mem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm probably being really dense here not understanding that, to clarify the problem seems to be the vector, as it errors on the 3rd iteration of trying to push an object back into the vector. should I be aligning the Prey object pointers I'm pushing into the vector to 16-bytes? if so any clues as to how? :D thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @TimLewis: Yip, any class or struct you create using XMVECTOR or XMMATRIX *must* be 16-byte aligned, using the template I provided above, just alter your `Prey` definition to: `__declspec(align(16)) class Prey : public AlignedAllocPolicy<16> { /* rest of class */}`, you could future-proof it a little more using `__alignof(XMVECTOR)` to get the correct alignment values. also remember C++ support multiple inheritance, so you can inherit for an allocation policy for vector objects while still inheriting from any other base class.