# XMMatrixTranspose Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I've got a DirectX 11 Project and I'm using the `Beginning DirectX 11 Game Programming` book going through all the chapters. I've got my Camera in place and it has been working with no crashes however recently when debugging my Obj Loader I've found that it keeps crashing on the `XMMatrixTranspose` line, I've swapped my view matrix and projection matrix round to see if it was specific to my view matrix which its not.

Here is the block of code that is causing the error

```
vMatrix = camera.GetViewMatrix();
vMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(vMatrix);

pMatrix = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(XM_PIDIV4, (float)(screenWidth / screenHeight), 0.01f, 100.0f);
pMatrix = XMMatrixTranspose(pMatrix);
```

This is found in my `DX11::Render` function. This is called in my `main.cpp` game loop as seen below.

```
MSG msg = { 0 };

while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        directX->Update(0.0f);
        directX->Render();
    }
}

directX->Shutdown();
```

All of my variables have memory and this code has been working before, when it started to do this it would do it very intermittently, but now it seems to be doing it all the time.

Any help and guidance would be amazing! I've been researching for hours and can't find anything that works and I've had this issue for about 7 hours! Its gotta go!!

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** It has now gone back to intermittently crashing

**UPDATE 2** I'm also using xnamath not DXMath

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dx11 Crash when accessing XMMATRIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133742/dx11-crash-when-accessing-xmmatrix)

Comment: Yes because that's using the XMMatrixTranspose function.

Comment: Zach, that problem with misaligned XMMATRIX variables is well known and gives just the symptoms you're seeing. I suggest you try the suggestions in the linked answer.

Comment: I'm not using DXMath either I'm using xnamath I'll update the question too

Comment: Note that Frank Luna's book is a good introduction to the DIrect3D 11.0 API, but makes heavy use of the legacy DirectX SDK which dates the book more than it would seem. D3DX11 is deprecated, XNAMath is replaced by DirectXMath, and Effects 11 has it's own set of caveats. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/04/07/book-recommendations.aspx)

Comment: Had I'd been doing this on my own back I may well have used DirectXMath but as its for my University course and the recommended reading specifies the book mentioned above I'm going to stick with it as that is what the book is compatible with and will still get me the grade I desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first read MSDN Programmer's Guide, specifically the [type usage guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418725(v=vs.85).aspx#type_usage_guidelines_).

> DirectXMath and XNAMath are basically the same library. XNAMath is just the old version of it which was last updated in 2011. You should move to using DirectXMath. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx).

The most likely problem is that you are trying to use `XMMATRIX` and/or `XMMVECTOR` types declared on the heap (i.e. in a class you use `new` on) which will *not* be properly aligned for x86 (32-bit) and ARM builds. It happens to line up for x64 native code, but that's mostly a happy accident.

In other words the following code will result in an AV in x86 (32-bit) and ARM depending on exactly how memory is laid out, but will work for x64 native:

```
struct A
{
    XMMATRIX m;
};

A a = new A;
a->m = XMMatrixIdentity();
```

To make it work robustly on all architectures, you need to use:

```
struct A
{
    XMFLOAT4X4 m;
};

A a = new A;
XMStoreFloat4x4(&A->m, XMMatrixIdentity());
```

You'd use `XMFLOAT4X4` or similar types which do not require alignment in your classes, and then use explicit Load/Save functions. Note that you can also make use of more compact forms like `XMFLOAT4X3` depending on your matrix content.

Alternatively, you can make use of the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) which does exactly that only "automagically" through the power of C++ conversion operators and constructors.

```
struct A
{
    Matrix m;
};

A a = new A;
A->m = XMMatrixIdentity();
// Note this is redundant
// as the Matrix default constructor sets it to identity already.
```

> This functionality is not part of the base library because it has some performance implications. By making it part of the SimpleMath wrapper instead, it allows users to opt in to an easier model of use while preventing accidental use of slower conversion paths for everyone else.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I did solve this without looking at your answer and found it to be because of the heap however considering your solution is actually more elegant and explains exactly what my problem was I've accepted it :)